# problems with delphi TIdUdpClient receiving data

Tags: delphi

I have a UDP communication to a Wago control with Modbus/UDP and had a lot of problem with TIdUdpClient.

Problem was that sending data always worked, but the component did not receive any data, even the response packet was clearly visible on WireShark.

I searched a long time until I found that the receive buffer Array MUST be set to the expected data length (NOT 0) as otherwise the client will not receive ANY data.

Just want to avoid others to search for hours.

Note: receive contains check of the error bit for Modbus function code. can be ignored, if you transmit other data than modbus

Working code example:

```
function TWagoIO.sendCommand (arucTX : array of Byte;     uiTXLen : integer;
                          var arucRX : array of Byte; var uiRXLen : integer) : boolean;
var
  clSocket   : TIdUdpClient;
  arTXBuff   : TIdBytes;
  arRXBuff   : TIdBytes;
  iIndex     : integer;
  iByteCount : integer;
  strPeerIP  : string;
  uiPeerPort : word;
  bRetValue  : boolean;

begin

  bRetValue := true;

  clSocket := TIdUdpClient.Create (nil);

  SetLength(arTXBuff, uiTXLen);

  for iIndex := 0 to (uiTXLen - 1) do
  begin
    arTXBuff [iIndex] :=  arucTX [iIndex];
  end;

  clSocket.Host := strIPAddress;
  clSocket.Port := uiPortNum;

  clSocket.SendBuffer(strIPAddress, uiPortNum, arTXBuff);

  SetLength(arRXBuff, 1024);
  strPeerIP  := '';
  uiPeerPort := 60000;
  Sleep (100);
  uiRXLen := clSocket.ReceiveBuffer(arRXBuff, strPeerIP, uiPeerPort, 3);
  if (uiRXLen > 7) then
  begin
    for iByteCount := 0 to uiRXLen do
    begin
      arucRX [iByteCount] := arRXBuff [iByteCount];
    end;

    if ((arucRX [7] and C_FC_ERROR_FLAG) = C_FC_ERROR_FLAG)  then
    begin
      bRetValue := false;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    bRetValue := false;
  end;
  clSocket.Destroy;

  result := bRetValue;
end;
```

Comment: Off-topic, but still important: You must use a `try..finally` block to protect the `clSocket` object. Otherwise, you'll leak it if an exception is raised. Also, when you destroy an object, you should use `X.Free`, not `X.Destroy`. (In this case it doesn't matter, but in many other cases it does, e.g. in a destructor.) Hence, you should do `clSocket := TIdUdpClient.Create(nil); try {all your code} finally clSocket.Free; end;`

Comment: It's encouraged for you to answer your own question below. It's not standard procedure to put an answer within the question.

Comment: @MartinWilde This is a Q&A site. There is no problem with sharing knowledge for the sake of sharing, but it still needs to be posted in a Q&A format. Please [edit] your post to ask a question (ie, "why do I not receive any data in this code?" and then post a separate answer for it (ie "because ReceiveBuffer() takes a pre-allocated buffer that must be large enough to receive the expected data". See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). And if you had found the solution to your problem elsewhere on StackOverflow, please link to that solution as well.